# Create TestSuite in JUnit5 (Eclipse)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I have created multiple Test case java files in eclipse and version of JUnit is JUnit5.

Now, I am trying to create a Junit TestSuite through the eclipse GUI and during the creation, I am not seeing the JUnit5 in the available versions.

This is the sample code that I have written for creation of TestSuite.

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeClassNamePatterns;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*Tests?")
@IncludeEngines("junit-jupiter")

public class AllTests {
}
```

This is the error I am getting while executing.

[image]

Should I do any manual setting to be able to create/run test suites?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When executing tests in a class annotated with `@RunWith`, that class is technically a JUnit 4 test class.

Thus, you have to execute your test suite using the "JUnit 4 Runner" in the "Run Configurations" of Eclipse.

See the following Eclipse bug for more information: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512772

Regarding the "JUnit Test Suite" dialog, that won't help you if you are using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` to execute a suite in JUnit 5.

Comment: Then what will be the way to create test suite in JUnit5?

Comment: If you are using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` that is technically a suite in JUnit 5. It is just that it uses JUnit 4 to _launch_ the JUnit 5 Platform.

Comment: Note, however, that we have plans to provide first-class support for suites in JUnit 5 that do not require a JUnit 4 _Runner_. For details, see all issues labeled with _suite_ in GitHub: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22theme%3A+suites%22

Answer (score 0):

you are not using JUnit5, Junit5 FQN is org.junit.jupiter.api.*

see https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php