# how to create test suite as in junit 4 using Junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5, junit-runner

as we are upgrading to junit5 from junit4 for unit testing purpose, i couldn't able to find solution to creating a test suite in junit5 like in junit4 :
below is the our junit4 suite class :

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    ClassA.class, 
    ClassB.class, 
    ClassC.class 
    } )
public class TestSuite {

}
```

The Code i tried after searching around is below :

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)

@SelectClasses( { 
    OrderAnnotationAlphanumericExperiment.class, 
    orderAnnotationExperiment.class, 
    ParameterizedAnnotation.class 
    } )
public class TestSuite {
    

}
```

on searching for the solution, most of them were providing a solution of using the same test suite to run it using vintage api, but what am looking for is to create test suite in junit 5.

Few suggesting *@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)*, but there is also less documentation for it, couldn't able to find a solution to create a suite in junit 5

few blogs/question/sites i referred :

[Create TestSuite in JUnit5 (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485339/create-testsuite-in-junit5-eclipse)
[Are test suites considered deprecated in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565724/are-test-suites-considered-deprecated-in-junit5)
https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-test-suites-examples/

some one help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this help: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips ? _"@RunWith no longer exists; superseded by @ExtendWith."_

Comment: `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SelectClasses( { 
 OrderAnnotationAlphanumericExperiment.class, 
 orderAnnotationExperiment.class, 
 ParameterizedAnnotation.class 
 } )
public class TestSuite {}`

Now i have tried this one! 
version of junit-jupiter-engine : 5.5.0
i have the following dependency still it throws error : *java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener*

Comment: I believe that the second code example you have is correct, according to the documentation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite

But as it is stated in the documentation:

"Test classes and suites annotated with @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) cannot be executed directly on the JUnit Platform (or as a "JUnit 5" test as documented in some IDEs). Such classes and suites can only be executed using JUnit 4 infrastructure."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are test suites considered deprecated in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565724/are-test-suites-considered-deprecated-in-junit5)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy. The following will find all JUnit tests in directory `foo.bar.tests` as well as it's subdirectories:

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("JUnit Platform Suite Demo")
@SelectPackages("foo.bar.test")
public class FullTestSuite
```

}

See [Sec 4.4.4 of the User's Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/).

Comment: This actually runs the test with the JUnit 4 engine, i.e. you'll need the `org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine` dependency.